# Command line argument to "find" and "grep" data inside "xattr -l" atrributes?

Tags: bash, metadata

I have a file that an application has set extended attributes for.

```
$ xattr -l /Volumes/Educating\ Rita\ \(1983\)/Educating\ Rita\ \(1983\).1.eng.srt
net.filebot.filename: 3_English.srt
net.filebot.metadata: {"@type":"Movie","year":1983,"imdbId":85478,"tmdbId":38291,"language":"en","id":38291,"name":"Educating Rita","aliasNames":[]}
```

I have tried a few different ways to get the value of `@type` inside the attribute but haven't found a way to search multiple files and grep for and return those values.

```
xattr -l /Volumes/Educating\ Rita\ \(1983\)/Educating\ Rita\ \(1983\).1.eng.srt | grep @type
net.filebot.metadata: {"@type":"Movie","year":1983,"imdbId":85478,"tmdbId":38291,"language":"en","id":38291,"name":"Educating Rita","aliasNames":[]}
```

I want to find every .srt file and `grep` for the value of `@type`. In the above results the command would return "Movie".

```
$ find . -iname "*.srt" | while read -r file; do `xattr -l "$file" | grep  "Type" >> /Users/john/Desktop/filebotmeta1.txt` ; done
```

That gives me a text document with this content:

```
net.filebot.metadata: {"@type":"Movie","year":1983,"imdbId":85478,"tmdbId":38291,"language":"en","id":38291,"name":"Educating Rita","aliasNames":[]}
```

But I want to return `@type` and it's value not the entire contents of the attribute.

I am not sure `getxattr` or `listxattr` apply to the command line. They seem to be for internal use only.

I imagine this involves outputting to a .tmp file and then grepping the contents of the file? Or, is there a one line argument I can use to print results in Terminal?

The contents look like `json` format.

Answer (score 2):

If you could be sure the file were `JSON` format, there might be a better way to do this, but you'd probably need to know something of the structure of the `JSON` records.

However, if I understand your question correctly, I think you can get what you want with `grep` if you use the `-o` or `--only-matching` option (see `man grep` for details)

```
# create a string 'STRINGX' to test a regex
% STRINGX='net.filebot.metadata: {"@type":"Movie","year":1983,"imdbId":85478,"tmdbId":38291,"language":"en","id":38291,"name":"Educating Rita","aliasNames":[]}'

# try a regex that includes '"@type": plus an alphanumeric string that follows
% echo $STRINGX | grep -o '\"@type\":\"[a-zA-Z0-9]*\"'

# which yields this as output:
"@type":"Movie"

# to print only the value of @type, one option is to use sed:
% echo $STRINGX | grep -o '\"@type\":\"[a-zA-Z0-9]*\"' | sed 's/^.\{8\}//' 
"Movie"
```

So - `pipe` your `xattr -l` output to the `grep` command as shown above.

You may be able to do a better job on the `regex` as I don't know if there are any rules that define characteristics such as maximum length, or presence of special characters, etc.

Let us know how this works, or if you have questions & we'll try to answer.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. I was wondering if there was a specific Apple binary that allows us to query the contents of a files' extended attributes directly. Similar to the way `PlistBuddy` allows us to interact with `.plist` files.

Comment: @John: `specific Apple binary...` Ummm - don't get me started, please :)